# SQL Server - Stored Procedure - Binary search algorithm

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've looking for how to create binary search procedure in sql, but i cant find it. Do you have any idea how can i do it?

Im using this test table:

```
declare @MyTable table (
    id int identity (1,1),
    UserName varchar(50),
    DNI int,
    Country varchar(50)
)
```

Suppose you have indexed the DNI field, which is the field we use to search the records. And therefore, they are ordered from highest to lowest. How can I obtain the data regarding a DNI, using the binary search?

Comment: Just use an index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know that the indexes increase the speed of the query in an incredible way, but I have a table with millions of data and I want to do faster searches with fewer iterations. If we use the logic of the binary search along with the effect of the indexes, I think you could have a query much faster and without consuming so many resources. What you think?

Comment: You don't have direct access to the data structures used to implement the tables so you can't. Most likely this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: And stop assuming an index is ordered in ascending order - that is simply the default.

Comment: The idea that any code written in T-SQL could outspeed the built-in algorithms for traversing B-tree indexes is just wrong. You don't really think the engineers at Microsoft would be unfamiliar with binary search as an algorithm, do you? Searching rows based on an index value is already an O(log n) operation. If your queries aren't fast enough, there's things you can do about it, but writing your own index search algorithm isn't one of them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are absolutely right, obviously they are the experts and they have done their best based on the best search algorithms. It does not make sense to create my own binary search algorithm when using the indexes, I would be using the algorithm implicitly

Comment: Certainly with using indexes for your search and not handcrafting search implementations for speed. SQL is a declarative language, you are free to say what data you require, you shouldnt need to/specify the path it should take. Let the optimizer do its work, to help the optimizer, keep the statistics up-date, constraints intact,store the correct data-type and you should be good.

Comment: As others have said, the index access code is already *very good*. And bear in mind, binary search is a great algorithm when working with *in memory* data structures. Not so much when you also have to account for I/O costs.

Answer (score 1):

> If we use the logic of the binary search along with the effect of the
>   indexes, I think you could have a query much faster and without
>   consuming so many resources. What you think?

I don't think so.  Even starting with a list of pages for a table, ordered by the key value (which SQL Server doesn't maintain) a BTree traversal would outperform a Binary Search.

A Binary Search of a sorted list eliminates half the target pages with each read.  If the rows are not distributed evenly, you could eliminate less than half the remaining rows with a read.

As you traverse a BTree you eliminate (N-1)/N of the rows, where N is the number of (index key, page pointer) tuples on a non-leaf page, typically in the 100s.  And since the tree is "balanced" you can consistently traverse to a the target page with 3 or 4 reads for any size table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement a binary search algorithm in TSQL (user level) faster that one implemented at the core level. However, you can create a clustered key (or clustered index for temporary table) on DNI column that physically reorganize the table data in memory in strict order. Hence, the search will be fastest.